# Why do we use an article for "the mind," "the heart," or "the soul"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

A student of mine came across a website titled "Music for the Mind" and asked why we use a definite article. We are not talking about a specific mind. We also use definite articles to talk about "The heart," "The soul".

Comment: Did you try a dictionary? This entry gives the following entry for [**the**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/the)  **e. Used as the equivalent of a possessive adjective before names of some parts of the body: *grab him by the neck; an infection of the hand*.** Voting to close this as general reference.

Comment: "We are not talking about a specific mind." Hmmm, another "rule" about English with exceptions. Time to expand the mind, I guess...

Comment: We could debate whether the usage is logical, but it is not specific to heart, mind, and soul. We use the definite article when the word is a countable noun, even when it's being used to refer to a "generic example" of that class. Like your music title example reminds me of Copland's "Fanfare for the Common Man", not "for Comman Man". Advertisers say "a gift for the woman in your life", not "... for woman ..." Etc. In some cases a plural would also work.

Answer (score 7):

In such cases the definite article is used to make a **generic reference**, with the result that the ‘noun phrase refers to the whole class, rather than just one or more instances of the class’(‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’).

Answer (score 3):

We can speak about *mind* or *the mind* when speaking generally. Check out the titles of [these philosophy books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_18?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=philosophy%20of%20mind&sprefix=philosophy%20of%20mind,aps,562): they all use "**Mind**", not "**The Mind**". Then check out [these science books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=the%20mind%20&rh=i%3aaps,k%3athe%20mind%20): they use "**The Mind**" not just "**Mind**". Perhaps the difference is that the philosophy books are talking about something abstract and the science books are talking about something concrete (many scientists reject the idea of a mind-body duality and insist that the mind is actually a set of measurable brain functions) and generic, as Barrie points out. In your examples, the words are used as generics and can be replaced by *your mind*. In the philosophy books, *mind* cannot be replaced by *your mind*.

Comment: And let's not forget: "[A mind](http://www.reference.com/motif/history/famous-quote-a-mind-is-a-terrible-thing-to-waste) is a terrible thing to waste."